# How do I use the the post method with fetch and koa?

Tags: node.js, frontend, fetch, backend, koa

This is a function on my front-end that makes the request.

```
function postNewUser(){
    
    fetch(`http://12.0.0.1:8080/users/test`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {nome: name, email: "test@test.com.br", idade: 20}
    })
}
```

This is my back-end code to receive the request.

```
router.post('/users/:id', koaBody(), ctx => {
  ctx.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  users.push(ctx.request.body)
  ctx.status = 201
  ctx.body = ctx.params
  console.log(users)
})
```

For some unknown reason I receive nothing. Not even a single error message. The "console.log()" on the back-end is also not triggered, so my theory is that the problem is on the front-end.

**Edit**

As sugested by **gnososphere**, I tested with Postman, and it worked. So now i know the problem must be on the fron-end code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try your backend functionality with [Postman](https://www.postman.com). It's a great service for testing.

[the request would look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzyPx.png)

If the problem is on the frontend, double check your fetch method by posting to a website that will return data and logging that in your app.

Comment: I tested with postman and it worked :) Now I know the problem is on the frontend. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I solved it. Your suggestion got me wondering if Postman made the code it used to make the request available, I went to look, and there it was. And actually it was available in various different languages. Thanks for your time, I really appreciated this.